# Самоддос на сайте

Tags: ddos, php, sql

Вообщем есть сайт раскрутки. Юзеры добавляют задания, например подписаться на Андрея, или лайкнуть запись и другие выполняют эти задания. Так вот, вчера решил написать бота, который будет выполнять задания за тебя. На PHP и JS. В БД лишь добавляется по 2 запроса. Изменения счётчика задания и начисление монет пользователю. Задержка стоит 20 секунд. То есть каждые 20 секунд на сервер посылается запрос. Задержка вида:

```
setTimeout(function() {
 _bot._reload();
}, 20000);
```

Стали очень много использовать бот, но изменять задержку на 1 секунду например и тем самым, устраивают самоддос сайту. Так вот хотел спросить. Есть такая функция **sleep()**, поставил sleep(20), и setTimeout естественно убрал. И просто всё настолько стало медленно грузить, что на сайт было вообще не попасть. Почему sleep(20) творит такие чудеса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Вы как я понял вставили sleep в PHP скрипт и естественно теперь отдача страница в браузер длится более 20 секунд а сайт "висит". Вот и вся магия.

Comment: @ReinRaus, в php скрипт вставлял, да. Но что делать тогда?

Comment: Сделайте в PHP лимит запросов от пользователя, на стороне клиента бороться не получится.

Comment: делайте проверку к примеру на сессиях, и сверяй сколько времени прошло, если меньше 20 сек, то говори о этом)

Comment: Только еще нужно учитывать, что идентификатор сессии может быть не передан и тогда начнется новая сессия. Сессии стоит использовать, если они используются для идентификации пользователя.

Comment: @ReinRaus, сессии это бред ещё тот. Сторонним сервером они обойдутся и забудутся. Сделаю круче.